# AVCaptureSession.Preset options

Tags: swift, xcode, video, photo

Looking over the AVCaptureSession.Preset options, is .photo the only choice for still photos and the rest are all for video capture? What's the difference between .low, .medium and .high and the others like .hd1920x1080? And how do you change the photo size like 4:3 and 16:9? Thanks

Comment: No offense intended. Just providing the opportunity to focus the question; sorry if that kind of assistance isn't desired. — "Are all those settings available to all iPhone models" Interesting question, but it wasn't part of the question posed. The way to know that is to call `canSetSessionPreset`, which also is explained by the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit confusing: `AVCaptureSession.Preset` doesn't tell you what the photo format or quality will be, it merely tells the AVCaptureSession to configure its inputs and outputs for a specified common use case. So you'd use `.photo` if you are only interested in photo output, and other modes when you are interested in some video output as well. I believe if you choose `.photo` and try to add a video output, you will get an error.

Photo size, much like in real camera, depends on the hardware, you cannot change directly how it's captured. You can, however, change various photo output options using `AVCapturePhotoSettings` and further process your photo with either [Core Graphics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics) or [Metal image filters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/image_filters)

I recommend to look at [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app) demo app apple provides, it will answer a lot of these questions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, personally I think Apple's documentation sucks. You look for something on their web site and you get such vague answers, so frustrating.

Comment: @mmoore410 yes, often docs don't tell you much, so it helps to look for their demos  and WWDC videos related to the topic you need. For example: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10247

Comment: More good information, thanks again. I can search forever and not find answers sometimes.